# "Especially those living in remote areas, might have never been to the capital."

Tags: sentence-structure, adverbs, subjects

Sentence:

> Especially those living in remote areas, might have never been to the capital.

**Question 1:** Does this sentence lack a subject? if so, why "those" can't be regarded as a subject?

**Question 2:** If I replace "especially" with "in particular", will it be different?

Comment: It isn't a complete sentence, and does lack a subject. I would expect the sentence to begin with a statement about the people of a country, which applies _especially_ to _those living in remote areas, **who** might never have been to the capital_. The same applies if you replace _especially_ with _in particular_.

Comment: Thank you so much.My translation teacher told me  if it replace especially with in particular,it will be right,but I can't really understand what she said.I thought they have similar function.I had written:especially for those people who lived in remote areas,they had never been to the capital.But I am still confused by "why thoes  can not be regarded as a subject directly,if we take especially as an adverb?

Comment: Yes, _especially_ and _in particular_ mean the same thing - I didn't mean to imply otherwise. But if you begin a sentence with _especially_, it looks as though there is something missing. I would suggest "Those people living in remote areas, especially/in particular, may never have been to the capital."

Comment: @KateBunting First of all the comma is not needed, and there are objections in style guides as to starting a sentence with "especially", when it emphasises the subject. But if we avoid those, it can be deemed as a complete sentence, with its subject explicitly mentioned.